# Unable to display an image in my view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to display an image (stored in my database) and I have some trouble with it.

I have the following code in my view:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("DownloadLogo", new { logoID = item.Logo.Key })" alt="" width="60" height="60">
```

And I have the following code in my controller:

```
    public FileContentResult DownloadLogo(int logoID)
    {
        LogoDTO logoDTO = _serviceClient.GetLogo(logoID);
        return File(logoDTO.LogoContent, logoDTO.LogoContentType);
    }
```

I got the error below when reaching the code in my view:

**HttpException**

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Before leaving the controller I check values:

logoDTO.LogoContent = {byte[50802]}
logoDTO.LogoContentType = "image/png"

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: This won't fix your Exception, but that Html.Action should be Url.Action instead. Html.Action will render an <a> tag inside your href attribute. Url.Action will only render the URL.

Comment: You solved my problem !!

Comment: Oh great. I added my comment as an answer so you can accept it, then others with this problem will know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html.Action should be Url.Action instead. Html.Action will render an  tag inside your href attribute. Url.Action will only render the URL.